# Regex to match the first element of the last line

Tags: python, regex

I have a table in the following format:

```
# HEADER
 1.452000000E-08   9.999999956E+00
 2.407483818E-06   9.999999956E+00
 1.096959505E-05   9.999999956E+00
 2.215696736E-05   9.999999961E+00
 3.187463656E-05   9.999999977E+00
 4.121852471E-05   1.000000002E+01
 4.981256454E-05   1.000000009E+01
 5.768279362E-05   1.000000017E+01
 6.495080199E-05   1.000000026E+01
 7.173653894E-05   1.000000035E+01
 7.813611913E-05   1.000000044E+01
 8.422150607E-05   1.000000053E+01
 9.004513021E-05   1.000000062E+01
 9.564467570E-05   1.000000071E+01
 1.010469937E-04   1.000000079E+01
 1.062711251E-04   1.000000087E+01
 1.113306207E-04   1.000000095E+01
 1.162353387E-04   1.000000103E+01
 1.209928265E-04   1.000000110E+01
 1.256093412E-04   1.000000116E+01
 1.300905579E-04   1.000000123E+01
 1.344420136E-04   1.000000128E+01
 1.386693389E-04   1.000000134E+01
 1.427783330E-04   1.000000138E+01
 1.467749408E-04   1.000000143E+01
```

I don't know the number of lines exactly, but I'd like to match the first element of the last line (ideally, I'd also get other elements for files with more columns). In this case, it is the number `1.467749408E-04`.

I can match the last line with `^[[:blank:]][-+]?\d*\.?\d+[eE][-+]?\d+(.*)\z` or the first column with `^[[:blank:]][-+]?\d*\.?\d+[eE][-+]?\d+` , but I can't figure out how to get the first element only, or do an AND that works with both of these conditions.

Comment: Is the data in some structure like an array? What language is the regex being used in?

Comment: tail -1 will give you the last line. awk will allow you to select the first element.

Comment: The data is always structured like that (number format always the same, and space between columns also always the same). The language I believe is PHP (it's in a python program that I'm using, and it just say "regex expression" to define a certain pattern).

Comment: @BalooRM I can only set the regex in an xml form.

Comment: Are you using PHP or Python?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The program is developed in Python, but I don't know how the regex was implemented. I said PHP because I managed to get other patterns using expressions that I got from PHP (maybe they were coincidentally the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using this regex pattern, in dot all mode:

```
^.*(\d+\.\d+E[+-]\d+)\s+\d+\.\d+E[+-]\d+$
```

### Demo

The pattern works as follows:

```
^                       from the start of the text
    .*                  consume everything, across lines, until reaching
    (\d+\.\d+E[+-]\d+)  the second to last number (capture this in $1)
    \s+                 followed by whitespace
    \d+\.\d+E[+-]\d+    the last number
$                       the end of the text
```

The number you are trying to target will be available in the first capture group.  How you would execute this regex and obtain the capture group would depend on the language/tool you are using.

Here is a Pythons script which should work:

```
inp = """# HEADER
1.452000000E-08   9.999999956E+00
...
1.467749408E-04   1.000000143E+01"""

matches = re.findall(r'^.*(\d+\.\d+E[+-]\d+)\s+\d+\.\d+E[+-]\d+$', inp,
                     flags=re.DOTALL)
print(matches[0])
```

This prints:

```
1.467749408E-04
```

Comment: I found an option to pass the dotall via the xml, and it worked! I also found that there was an option to print the last match, which also worked with the number in the beginning of the line expression I had... :) Thanks, anyway!

Comment: Actually, I may have said too soon: For some reason, the program still prints the first match (1.452000000E-08), even with the dotall="true" option. I can get the one I want adding the "last" option. However, as your code does work as I asked, this is a correct answer.